# hazelcast client unable to connect to server

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast (hazelcast client and server jars on the client side and server jar on the server - both versions are the same i.e. 3.2.4).  The server is running on a different box - I specified that IP address in my client.  It appears that the server is running (I can see that the process is up and binding on the 5701 port).  My client tries to connect to the remote IP address and port but is unable to do so and the hazlecast messages do not help much (unless I misconfigured logging).  Output below:

```
Sep 04, 2014 8:30:45 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.4] is STARTING
Sep 04, 2014 8:30:46 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.4] is STARTED
Sep 04, 2014 8:30:49 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService
WARNING: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
Sep 04, 2014 8:30:52 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService
WARNING: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 2 of 2.
Sep 04, 2014 8:30:55 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService
```

**Config file section:**

```
<network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false" />
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <salt>fakesalt</salt>
            <password>fakepwd</password>
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
```

any help in troubleshooting would be great

**Edit**
I was able to vlaidate network traffic between the two servers (hosting the client and server via port 5701) using iperf.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, TCP port 5701
TCP window size:  101 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 40937 connected with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 5701
[  5] local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 5701 connected with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 51788
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  3.31 GBytes  2.84 Gbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  3.20 GBytes  2.75 Gbits/sec
```

Comment: is the port on the remote host accessible? can you ping the remote host from the client host, can you telnet? is the remote port open etc?

Comment: its open and I can telnet to it

Comment: think I am ableto connect - will post update shortly

Comment: just did - I copied the network part.  Thinking of turning the auto increment to off.

Comment: could you also add your client code (or well how you try to connect) and how you are creating your server?

Comment: added this in the other question you responded to

Comment: I added some info on why you are getting multiple instance in that question, could you also add the client code with which you are connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the hazelcast-client config file and preferably test via tcp/ip using a simple server and client.

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-client-config-3.1.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name> 
        <password>dev-pass</password> 
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
       <cluster-members>
            <address>127.0.0.1</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-pool-size>30</connection-pool-size>

        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
                <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                <region>us-west-1</region>
                <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false" />
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <password>thepass</password>
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
<!-- additional tags -->
</hazelcast-client>
```